# rfc2104 MD5 issue

Tags: c#, hash, cryptography, md5

Can someone give me an example in c# how to HASH string with MD5, regarding this document : http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2104.txt

I was used MD5CryptoServiceProvider but without success.
I`m trying to communicate with external software and we must have same HASH.
Asked their developers and they told me that use this alogirtm : http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2104.txt

So my question is how to make my HASH equals to their.. 
Thank you very much in advice ..

Comment: Have you looked at an example in MSDN? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**

As per your comment i have removed my previous answer as it was misunderstood.
i have tried something new hope this helps

HMAC key (in hexadecimal format)

```
  string key = "52320e181a481f5e19507a75b3cae4d74d5cfbc328f7f2b738e9fb06b2e05b55b632c1c3d331dcf3baacae8d3000594f839d770f2080910b52b7b8beb3458c08";
        string payload = "1116Software program14200503031234341420050303123434";


        int NumberChars = key.Length;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i += 2)
            bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(key.Substring(i, 2), 16);

        byte[] keyInBytes = bytes;

        byte[] payloadInBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload);

        var md5 = new HMACMD5(key);//This should match with service key

        byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(payloadInBytes);

        var result = BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", string.Empty);
```

you should have a key and that key must be equal to the key used in the service you are referring to.then the result will be same

Comment: No , you don`t understand me .. I know how to convert string to MD5. But result from my MD5 and service MD5 are different .. For example this string : 1116Software program14200503031234341420050303123434 , my result is : 6bd4cfaafe4e9a6c2969589385d47171 , but result from service is : 7bf97ed39681027d0c45aa45e3ea98f0 , so our HASH was different and that is the problem .. They use this algorithm : http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2104.txt , if this can help .. Thank you for your response.

Comment: ok sorry for the misunderstanding .the Doc you provided is dated 1997 and using C and some coding styles that are not at all used. :) Need to  dig a bit more to find your solution. i am tying lets see if can come up with some thing

Comment: @HarryBirimirski To you have a `HMAC key`??

Comment: No , i don`t have HMAC key :(

Comment: Get the key from their developers and everything works with your code. Thank you very much